# Fixing errors upgrading from Angular 2 to 5?

Tags: javascript, angular

Can anybody help me figure out what is wrong with these imports? I upgraded from Angular 2 to 5 (big jump, I know) and have a couple dependency errors. They include:

```
import { NgModule, Inject } from '@angular/core';
```

Error:

```
[ts] Cannot find module '@angular/core'.
```

Also...

```
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
```

Error:

```
[ts] Module '"/Users/laurenhesterman/Desktop/StormSensor/front- 
stormsensor/node_modules/@angular/http/index"' has no exported member ' 
HttpModule'.
```

What might I need to change to fix these?

Thanks so much! Let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 0):

For the first you can do `npm -i @angular/core —save`.

To solve the second you could try to use `import {HttpClientModule} from ‘@angular/common/http`.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems the problem was just related to my IDE (vs Code) rather than my project. It wasn't reading my dependencies correctly after I updated. What I did was:

1.Open a TypeScript file. 2.Click the TypeScript version to the bottom right in the Status Bar. 3.Choose Use Workspace Version from the message box.

See here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34681